# .net Core Solution - Project stucture

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I want create a solution with VS Code.

All projects will be .Net Core projects. In this solution there will be shared library projects, a web API project, a react web site project.

Shared libraries will be used by other projects in the solution.

I couldn't find any good example to create solution similir to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the community editon of visual studio 2019. It has a project template, that contains a .net core project providing the server side and a react app for the frontend. You can the easily add a library project. I would suggest you use .Net Standard for that.

New Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Application -> React.js

Edit:

Ok the official template looks like this:

- SolutionFile

  - ASP.NET Core Web Application Project

    - ClientApp (Contains the react app)
    - Controllers (Your API controllers)
    - Programm.cs
    - Startup.cs
  - Library Projects

Comment: If I understood it correctly you want a Solution file with a react js project, a .net core api project and some .net core libraies and looking for a structure

Comment: It is correct. But I can't to use Visual Studio 2019, Everything is on linux.

Answer (score 0):

> *IMP: I do not have enough so reputation to add comment*

keep the shared project outside of all other .net core app/library that has reference, and use **dotnet add** reference command to refer them where ever you need.

> [dotnet add reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference)

if you want to create solution file use, **dotnet new sln** command .
use **dotnet sln** command to change solution file created.

> [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)
>   [dontet sln](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln)

use **workspace option available in VS Code**. and save them(workspace) for feature reference and it comes handy during debugging.

hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to create solution and add reference to it. My question is different. I want to find a good example with explanation for my coworker.

Comment: Hope this may help you! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-with-cli

Comment: If you want specific tutorial on project/solution structure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-with-cli